# Multivariable Integration by parts (basic)

Tags: calculus, integration

Use integration by parts twice on 
$ \int e^{xy} \cos(y) dy$

i wanna integrate $\cos(y)$ first  and derivate $e^{xy}$  since x is a constant of the integration.

we have $e^{xy} \sin(y)$ + $ \int xe^{xy} \sin(y) dy$

followed by

$e^{xy} \sin(y)$ + $ xe^{xy} \cos(y) dy$ + $ \int -x^{2}e^{xy} \cos(y) dy$

This doesnt look right....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks right.

Let
$$I=\int e^{xy}\cos ydy$$
Then, as you have calculated,
$$I=e^{xy}\sin y+xe^{xy}\cos y-x^2I$$
Therefore,
$$I=\frac{e^{xy}\sin y+xe^{xy}\cos y}{1+x^2}$$

Comment: wow really? i haven't done an integration by parts in years and i couldn't even find my textbook with the formula! thx i couldnt remember the trick from there tyvm